# Prospective PhD advisor wrote that he would get back to me, but did not. What should I do?

Tags: phd

Prospective PhD advisor wrote that he would get back to me in "two weeks or so", and it has been 3 weeks now. Should I email him? What should I write in the email?

Comment: If the advisor is in the US, note that this is the week of Thanksgiving...

Comment: @JonCuster Oh you're right. I totally forgot. But do people celebrate the whole week there?

Comment: Well, students are leaving (my kids are back home), which means dealing with lots of last-second requests, then many folks travel (even in a pandemic - sigh) anytime from last weekend through Thursday morning, then back again on Sat/Sun. Lots of time off to bake pies. Generally a mess... Drop a follow up email on, say, Tuesday next week.

Comment: @JonCuster I do not want the professor to think that I am not interested or something. If I were to email after a month, wouldn't it look like that I am not excited about joining his research team?

Comment: @JonCuster And also, What should I write in the email? English is my third language, and sometimes writing emails in english, I feel like what I am writing might come off as rude.

Comment: I would say maybe 10% of Profs. would take a whole week off. Most profs I know are responsive on weekends, holidays, etc except when they announce they are off for a family time, etc. I doubt that is the reason you didn't hear back.

Comment: Wait one more week.

Comment: @Alchimista What do you recommend that I write in the email that wouldn't seem rude?

Comment: I would continue as in the previous contact. An email isn't rude. After you can even call. A friend of mine was complaining of no answer then, when I have convinced her to insist and finally call, got a post doc position in matter of days. Spam box was the case.... There is nothing wrong on "insisting". He said 2 week or so, so after 25 days you should show up again (in person, by mail, by phone depending on the situation).